# issue while calculating the exact date when user has given the date and displaying at the position

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am working on angularjs google chart API timeline chart.
I have to show the image on h-axis based on the dates given by the user.
Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/aKmf4QkK7AhjJX1eH4J9?p=preview

Below is the code used to pass the dates to the function where it calculates and dislay the image.

```
            var overlay;
            var overlayCount = overlays.length;
          // remove existing overlays
            while (overlayCount--) {
                overlay = overlays[overlayCount];
                if (overlay !== null) {
                    container.removeChild(overlay);
                }
                overlays.splice(overlayCount, 1);
            }
            overlays.push(setOverlay(new Date(2018,7, 8)));
            overlays.push(setOverlay(new Date(2018, 6, 9)));

            overlays.push(setOverlay(new Date(2018,6, 8)));
            overlays.push(setOverlay(new Date(2018, 5, 9)));
```

It is showing the image at the position assigned by `overlay.style.bottom` which fails when the number of records getting dynamically are more or less.How to calculate and assign the value for overlay.style.bottom dynamically . Any inputs would be helpful.

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope,$timeout) {
        var chart1 = {};
        chart1.type = "Timeline";
        chart1.displayed = false;
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline')
        chart1.data = {
            "cols": [{
                id: "month",
                label: "Month",
                type: "string"
            }, {
                id: "laptop-id",
                label: "Laptop",
                type: "string"
            }, {
                id: "desktop-id",
                label: "start",
                type: "date"
            }, {
                id: "server-id",
                label: "end",
                type: "date"
            }],
            "rows": [{
                c: [{
                    v: "January"
                }, {
                    v: "text here",
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 3, 1),p: {id: 1001}
                }, {
                    v:new Date(2018, 4, 12)
                } ]
            },{
                c: [{
                    v: "January"
                }, {
                    v: "text here",
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,4, 15),p: {id: 1002}
                }, {
                    v:new Date(2018, 4, 22)
                } ]
            },{
                c: [{
                    v: "January"
                }, {
                    v: "text here",
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 5, 1),p: {id: 1003}
                }, {
                    v:new Date(2018, 5, 12)
                } ]
            }, {
                c: [{
                    v: "February"
                }, {
                    v: "feb text here"
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,4, 1),p: {id: 1004}
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 4, 15)
                } ]
            } , {
                c: [{
                    v: "april"
                }, {
                    v: "april text here"
                }, { 
                    v: new Date(2018,5, 1),p: {id: 1005}
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 7, 15)
                } ]
            } , {
                c: [{
                    v: "may"
                }, {
                    v: "may text here"
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 7, 1),p: {id: 1006}
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 8, 15)
                } ]
            } , {
                c: [{
                    v: "june"
                }, {
                    v: "some text here"
                }, { 
                    v: new Date(2018,6, 1),p: {id: 1007}
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 6, 10)
                } ]
            },{
                c: [{
                    v: "june"
                }, {
                    v: "some text here"
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,6, 15),p: {id: 1008}
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 6, 22)
                } ]
            }  ]
        };
        chart1.options = {
            timeline: {
                showRowLabels: false,
            },
        };

        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.selected();
        }, 1000);
        $scope.selected = function(selectedItem) {
          var numberOfRows = chart1.data.rows.length;
        //  alert("rows length : " + numberOfRows);
       }

        $scope.myChart = chart1;

    });
```

Comment: the image is always at the same position because of --> `overlay.style.bottom =315 + 'px';`

Comment: Is there a way to calculate overlay.style.bottom dynamically ,as the data i get is dynamic and if i give the static value the image position will vary , Please find the example demo https://plnkr.co/edit/aKmf4QkK7AhjJX1eH4J9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

you can use --> (number of rows * row height)

and you want to use `overlay.style.top` not `bottom`

`bottom` will position the overlay # of pixels from the bottom of the page

replace...

```
overlay.style.bottom =315 + 'px';
```

with...

```
overlay.style.top = ((chart1.data.rows.length * 42) + 8) + 'px';
```

`42` is the approximate row height
`8` is half the image height in the example

**edit**

since the timeline groups by row label,
you can use an array to save the distinct labels,
then use the length of the array for the height...

```
    var groupRows = [];
    chart1.data.rows.forEach(function (row) {
      if (groupRows.indexOf(row.c[0].v) === -1) {
        groupRows.push(row.c[0].v);
      }
    });
    overlay.style.top = ((groupRows.length * 42) + 8) + 'px';
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I wonder like if we have multiple rows showing in the same row because it has same ID,then it would fail in my scenario as i have to know exact number of rows to assign the image at particular pixel((chart1.data.rows.length * 42) + 8) + 'px') . Please find the updated link https://plnkr.co/edit/DIL1utEJB9RgolZm2Wa7?p=preview . It has 8 data rows displayed on the chart but displayed in 5 rows on the chart, as my data is dynamic how can i know that the rows are being shown in 5 rows on that chart. Please advice.

Comment: you could use the [`group()` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) to group on id and get the number of rows from the resulting data table...

Comment: Can you please suggest how to use group() method to group on ID. I am still in search for this solution.

Comment: don't think the `group()` method will work for you, you'd have to use `google.visualization`, see __edit__ above...